# The implementation of a multi-state model in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a **QUESTION model** in the test system.
The question may be different (with text, with picture, etc)
The answer may be different (textfield, checkboxes, etc)

How to implement this in MVC correctly?

[**Picture for understanding**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O8fC.jpg)

Comment: Can you make the question more specific? The model would be pretty much independent of the MVC pattern.

Comment: Model is a layer, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Business/Domain Objects:

```
public class Question {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public Answer CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class Answer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class QuestionViewModel {
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty good but what about extensibility?
For example i need a new type of answer: "World War II. Input date range."
[textfieldStart] - [textfieldEnd] (two answer fields, not one)

Comment: that's what `Question.Answers` is for ... you can display n answers. Though, there's only one `CorrectAnswer`. If there are multiple correct answers then create a list of `CorrectAnswers` as a member of `Question`.

Comment: I wanted split it by parts (everything with own logic)  [pic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZPfx.jpg) 
But your answer seems fairly universal.